# Kotlin app build failed due to "Could not initialize class com.intellij.ide.highlighter.JavaFileType"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I've just updated Android Studio to 2.2 and now my Kotlin project won't build. The gradle synch works fine, but when attempting to build I'm immediately presented with an error that reads:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not initialize class com.intellij.ide.highlighter.JavaFileType
```

I've checked that my Kotlin plugin is up to date. This error sounds like something to do with the IDE and highlighting Java code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which Kotlin compiler version are you referencing in your build.gradle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open `Tools | Kotlin | Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates` in the main menu,
then choose `Check for Updates`. Be sure that yo're using `Stable` channel.

Close `Android Studio`, go to your project's directory, and delete `build` and `app/build` folders. Run Android Studio. Deleted folders would be recreated.

Hope it will help

Comment: Yes, this was the solution (worked it out myself, but ups to you for following through with such a nice clear answer).

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the kotlin plugin was not updated as @piotrek1543 said in other answer.

In addition to that the `build.gradle` had an old Kotlin version number `1.0.1-2` and the IntelliJ said in a warning on top of to switch to the current bundled version `1.0.4`.

Now with the kotlin version like this the error is gone:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.4'
```